# Show Review Form without Reviews

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

i want a problem right now.

I want to display the Review Form after the Body inside a Modal, it´s working good only one "bug".

inside catalog.xml

catalog_product_view

```
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

it displays the reviews with the stars also, how can i turn it that it will only display the forms?

FIXED VERSION

```
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: You can find the form in this file - review/product/view/list.phtml Try to modify that.

Comment: thank you, but i know that the form is there, how can i display with above code only the form and not both

Comment: @Shain That's great that you fixed it yourself! Instead of editing the fixed code into the question, it's better for future visitors if you provide an answer to your question with the details of how you fixed it.